# Any way to stop youtube or videos in chrome from playing over bluetooth in car?

Tags: bluetooth, android-10

Are there permission settings to block apps from playing over bluetooth? Every time I've been messing around on the internet or youtube and my android phone connects to the car, the last video I've watched appears on the head unit. I only want to allow play music to stream over bluetooth; nothing else...

The only way I've managed to get this to work is by using an automate flow, but I feel this should be built in functionality.

https://llamalab.com/automate/community/flows/6043